# Use static final unmodifiable Set as constant for checking variables value

Tags: java, coding-style

I've often run through a validation pattern where, to be valid, some variables must contain one of a prefixed number of values.

```
PSEUDO CODE:
    IF x == CONSTANT_1 || X == CONSTANT_2 || ... || x == CONSTANT_N
    THEN X is valid
```

In order to avoid the chain of OR terms, I created a static final unmodifiable set, which contains all the constants:

```
public final static String CONSTANT_1 = *value* ;
public final static String CONSTANT_2 = *value* ;
...
public final static String CONSTANT_N = *value* ;

public final static Set SET_OF_CONSTANTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {
        add(CONSTANT_1); 
        add(CONSTANT_2);
        ...
        add(CONSTANT_3);
    }
});
```

And I perform the check in the following way:

```
if(!SET_OF_CONSTANTS.contains(x)){ 
    //X NOT VALID 
}
```

I'd like to know if this is a good programming practice, if there are any alternatives, and if it's true that using a Hash Table query (O(1) in theory) instead of the OR terms-chain improves performance and maybe also code-readability.

Comment: I think this is very good style. As far as performance goes, I wouldn't try to optimize anything until I've profiled the application on typical data.

Comment: +1 for NPE. Never presume where your performance bottleneck is and never optimize prematurely

Comment: Yes, it's true. There's also an alternative, EnumSet, which is implemented as bit set operations. Though it might not be usable as a in-place replacement, it could require API change.

Comment: **Note:** Comparing strings with `==` is wrong most of the time. In most cases, you have to use `aString.equals(otherString)`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: why not a hashmap since the constants are key value pairs ?

Comment: Thanks Philipp, but I really know what's the difference between == and equals. The first part of my post, where I use ==, is to be intended as pseudo code and not Java code. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Overall, I think this is very good style.

There's not a huge difference, but I'd personally define `SET_OF_CONSTANTS` like so:

```
      public final static String CONSTANT_1 = "*value*";
      public final static String CONSTANT_2 = "*value*";
              ...
      public final static String CONSTANT_N = "*value*";

      public final static Set<String> SET_OF_CONSTANTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
              CONSTANT_1, 
              CONSTANT_2,
                      ...
              CONSTANT_N
              )));
```

It's not entirely clear to me whether you even need the separate `CONSTANT_1` constants, or whether you can simply fold the values into `SET_OF_CONSTANTS`.

As far as performance goes, I would not start optimizing anything until I've profiled the code on real data.

Finally, note that when `x` is a string, the following is probably incorrect:

```
IF x == CONSTANT_1 || x == CONSTANT_2 || ... || x == CONSTANT_N
```

Here, the `==` should probably be replaced with calls to `equals()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Anyway I know what's the difference between == and equals. The first part of my post, where I use ==, is to be intended as pseudo code and not Java code. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I edited my post.

Comment: (Or `==` is right and you should use `Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashSet<>(...))` but that leaves what to use for `...`. Unlikely, I admit.)

Answer (score 2):

Another (shorter) way would be to use Set.of :

```
public final static Set SET_OF_CONSTANTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
    Set.of(CONSTANT_1, CONSTANT_2, CONSTANT_3));
```

Comment: Correct answer since Java9.

Comment: Requires java 9.